# AutoFixture RepeatCount

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Is there a way to know the RepeatCount from a ISpecimenBuilder? I am creating a new specimen builder for certain parameter name. Basically the Create method will ask for the parameter name and in case it is e.g. "myParamName", and the type is e.g. "MyParamType" it will return a customized object.

This works perfect, however, if the parameter type is IEnumerable{MyParamType} I would like to "CreateMany". The problem is...how many?

I cannot call context.Resolve or context.CreateMany{MyParamType} for the simple reason that it would not create my objects the way I need. Example: if MyParamType is string, it would not create the formatted string I need. That is exactly why I created a specimen builder in the first place!:) I also cannot register my new specimen builder for MyParamType as I only need this customization for parameter value requests of a specific name. Otherwise, I need the default behavior

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're trying to do, but you don't have to worry about handling requests for `IEnumerable<T>` in your custom specimen builder; AutoFixture will [automatically convert](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/ab829640ed8e02776e4f4730d0e72ab3cc382339/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/EnumerableRelay.cs#L9-L10) requests for `IEnumerable<T>` into *multiple requests* for `T`, which is then handled by your specimen builder.

For example, let's assume we have a custom specimen builder that simply return the value `"foo"` for all requests for `string`:

```
public class FooBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        return request.Equals(typeof(string))
            ? (object)"foo"
            : new NoSpecimen();
    }
}
```

Now, this test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void Should_return_all_foos_for_a_sequence_of_strings()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture { RepeatCount = 4 };
    fixture.Customizations.Insert(0, new FooBuilder());

    var many = fixture.Create<IEnumerable<string>>();

    Assert.Equal(4, many.Count());
    Assert.All(many, i => Assert.Equal("foo", i));
}
```

because AutoFixture makes sure to invoke the `FooBuilder` as many times as it's needed in order to satisfy the request.

Comment: Suppose that your specimen builder returns foo only if the request is for a parameter of type string and name fooParam. How would your fixture manage a request for a param of type IEnumerable of string and name fooParam as well? I think it would create standard strings and not e.g. "foo".

Comment: @AdanayMartín Correct. You'd have to handle requests for `ParameterInfo` of type `IEnumerable<string>` but that's _before_ AutoFixture unwraps it into multiple requests for `string`. If you _really_ need to know the value of `RepeatCount` from a custom specimen builder, you can do `((Fixture)((SpecimenContext)context).Builder).RepeatCount` but I wouldn't go down that route without first evaluating how important it is for the tests that your builder honors that property. Chances are you'll be fine by simply returning a fixed number of specimens.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You are right. The property itself is not that important since I can return a random number of elements. I am just exploring the possibilities with AutoFixture and sometimes I wonder if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is...how many?

By default, that's 3. You may change this parameter when creating a new `Fixture` instance:

```
  var fixture = new Fixture { RepeatCount = 4 };
```

Comment: Um, that is not really the answer. I need to know this value from inside the Create method of my specimen builder such that I will create myself a list of RepeatCount customized objects.